# Is it possible to run the Steam version of GTA 4 on Ubuntu?

Tags: steam, grand-theft-auto-iv, ubuntu

Is it possible to run GTA4 from Steam on Ubuntu? How would I go about installing it from my Steam client? Do I need to use some sort of Windows application wrapper like Wine? And can I play multiplayer without any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, you will need to use an application like WINE.  You can also use PlayOnLinux (which is actually based on WINE) which is designed to make it easier to play Windows games.  As it happens, [GTA IV is listed as a supported game](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/supported_apps-1-0.html).

You can get instructions on how to download the program from their site [here](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html).  Simply select your distribution (either of the Debian or Ubuntu methods should work for you).  Once you get the program downloaded you need to get your games installed.  There is a visual guide they provide [here](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/manual.html).  From what I can tell, in order to run a steam copy of a game you need the windows version of steam installed, which also appears to be installable from within PlayOnLinux according to [this page](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_under_Linux).

I wish I could give you some personal experience here but I dual-boot so I haven't needed PlayOnLinux, but it looks like it should do the trick given they list GTA 4 as a supported piece of software.

Comment: I downloaded Steam for Windows and ran it using Wine. Then I downloaded and installed GTAIV. When I try to launch the game I get this error message: "The program LaunchGTAIV.exe has encountered a serious problem and needs to close."

Comment: Did you install steam through the PlayOnLinux or did you install it yourself? The last link I put suggests that you need to install Steam through PlayOnLinux, not into WINE manually. We may need input from someone with more experience using PlayOnLinux software.

Comment: Installed Steam and GTA4 via PlayOnLinux. When I try to launch the game I get an error saying DFA did not initialize properly.

Comment: After a google search, the only thing I came up with is [this forum post](http://forum.overclock3d.net/showthread.php?s=da723a3ad98aeb3f8b0f3c21385ddbeb&t=43990&page=2) which says this problem can happen when an essential .NET component is missing, which happens to come with the Windows Live Essentials (messenger program).  You could try installing that within WINE/PlayOnLinux.  You may want to wait and see if anyone else knows a fix, I have no personal experience using this; I only know what I gathered from those links in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

According to Steam. GTA IV originally is Windows based game. So if I can only suggest you to test and try it by yourself.
[image: GTAIV]